# How to have conditions for two values with laravel eloquent `when` instead of if-elseif

Tags: laravel, if-statement, eloquent

How can I convert this:

```
if(isset($from) && isset($to))
{
    $query->where('column1', $from)->where('column2', $to);
}
elseif(isset($from))
{
    $query->where('column1', $from);
}
elseif(isset($to))
{
    $query->where('column1', $to);
}
```

to something like this with `when` in Laravel:

```
...
->when(isset($from) && isset($to), function($query) use ($from, $to)
{
    $query->where('column1', $from)->where('column2', $to);
})
->elseWhen(isset($from), function($query) use ($from)
{
    $query->where('column1', $from)->where('column2', $from);
})
->elseWhen(isset($to), function($query) use ($to)
{
    $query->where('column2', $to);
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use the 2nd one, if the 1st one already solves your problem?

Comment: because maybe user has set only `from` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `when` like this :

```
...
->when(isset($from), function($query) use ($from)
{
    return $query->where('column1', $from);
})
->when(isset($to), function($query) use ($to)
{
    return $query->where('column2', $to);
});
```

In this case if the two values are set then you will get the exact same result of you first if condition :)

Comment: That's right but I need those variables to be used in another query inside that when, fetch data and use fetched data for next query.

Comment: you can use it in the other queries but after that you should return the query builder !

Comment: Yeah Thanks :))

Answer (score 1):

You can use `orWhere` e.g.

```
 $query->where('column1', $from)->orWhere('column2', $to);
```

This will replace all the code above (I mean the if's). I believe this is optimized query as you don't need to use `when`.